# How can I do multivariate random forest in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, random-forest

I've written some scripts in Python that can do multivariate random forest regression using scikit learn. Scikit learn is able to do multivariate problems (http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems). However, it seems that Matlab's treebagger class is only able to predict on a single variable. My variables are correlated so I want to avoid running two independent models in Matlab. Is there a way to do multivariate regression using Matlab's treebagger? If not, is there other Matlab code out there that could do that?

Comment: @Amro I noticed that you have answered very well other questions regarding random forest, decision trees, or regression in general.  Could you point me in the right direction on this?  I'd like to make a standalone Matlab app that can do multivariate random forest, but it doesn't seem like treebagger or other random forest packages for Matlab can do this.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to the question?